# Python change dictionary value with values in array

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-2.7, dictionary

Here's the code I am using. I need to be able to change the value of `test["test1"]["test2"]["test3"]` from values contained in a list.  This list could become longer or shorter.  If the key doesn't exist I need to be able to create it.

```
test = {"test1": {"test2": {"test3": 1}}}

print test["test1"]["test2"]["test3"]
# prints 1

testParts = ["test1", "test2", "test3"]

test[testParts] = 2

print test["test1"]["test2"]["test3"]
# should print 2
```

Comment: The techniques in my answer there apply here too; use reduce() to walk to the innermost dictionary (creating additional dictionaries as needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try

```
test[testParts] = 2
```

you will get a `TypeError`, because `testParts` is a list, which is mutable and unhashable and therefore cannot be used as a dictionary key. You can use a tuple (immutable, hashable) as a key:

```
testParts = ("test1", "test2", "test3")
test[testParts] = 2
```

but this would give you

```
test == {('test1', 'test2', 'test3'): 2, 'test1': {'test2': {'test3': 1}}}
```

There is no built-in way to do what you are trying to do, i.e. "unpack" `testParts` into keys to nested dictionaries. You can either do:

```
test["test1"]["test2"]["test3"] = 2
```

or write a function to do this yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I think this solves my issue.  I'll mark the correct answer when I can.

Comment: The answer to Martijn's linked question covers a great approach to "writ[ing] a function to do this yourself".